# how to force text inside a div

Tags: css, html

I'm having a little problem with my website. I have 3 three boxes side by side(box1, box2, box3). The text in Box1 will be generated dynamically according to the date().

The problem I'm having is that..some text in box1 seems to be pushing the boxes and icons on the other boxes upwards.

```
CSS

.box1{
margin-left: 0px;
margin-top: 60px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-color:#D8D8D8 ;  
position: relative; 

}

.box2{ 
 margin-left: 350px;
 margin-top: -200px;
  width: 300px;
height: 200px; 
background-color:#D8D8D8 ; 
}

.box3{
margin-left: 700px;
margin-top: -200px;
 width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background-color:#D8D8D8 ; 
}

.result{
        color :teal ;  
        font-family: cambria; 
        font-weight: normal; 
        text-align:center; 
        font-size:1.85em; 
         margin-top: 0px;   

}

.mic{
 position: absolute;
margin-left: 250px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

.clock{
 position: absolute;
margin-left: -460px;
margin-top: -25px;
}

.calendar{
position: absolute;
margin-left: 940px;
margin-top: -25px;
}
```

The 3 examples are in the image below

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to use absolute positions for those boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Try this little ditty:

```
.prevent-text-breakouts {
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-all;
      word-break: break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
          hyphens: auto;
}
```

You can also look into using the overflow attribute on those boxes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out what "text" is being added into the **Result** div when the error occurs. It could be that malformed HTML is being inserted somehow.
2. You can clean up your CSS a lot by using **float:left;** instead of positioning the elements based on excessive margins. If you want me to elaborate, let me know.

Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dEhEt/5/

It doesn't include the icons for each box, but there are a number of different ways to achieve that effect, and I'll let you decide which one you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please explain further.

Comment: The abnormality only occurs in the second instance (image)

Comment: What I mean is, look at the html inside of the result div (that is messed up) once it has been generated. An image won't give me that information.

Comment: I checked source after error display, and the HTML is not breaking.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a little unclear about your problem. Is the box always being displayed incorrectly, or only under certain circumstances?

Comment: In all the 3 examples of the boxes... The second display in the first box (row2, col1)is shifting the other two boxes(row2, col2 and row2, col3) on it's right upwards... But in the other two examples(row1, col1 and row3, col1) the text in the text box are well displayed without shifting the other boxes on it's right upwards.

Comment: So, if the second example is the only instance where there is a display issue, find out what the difference is between the two. Without HTML snippets of your code, this is all I can really do.